# change socket to other then default in phpPgAdmin

Tags: postgresql

I need to change the socket phpPgAdmin connects to in its config.

```
// Hostname or IP address for server.  Use '' for UNIX domain socket.
// use 'localhost' for TCP/IP connection on this computer
$conf['servers'][0]['host'] = '/opt/jasperreports-server-cp-5.1.0/postgresql';
$conf['servers'][0]['defaultdb'] = 'postgres';
```

this does not work.
leaving it empty `''` doesn't work too.

In pg_hba.conf I have only the following line:

```
local   all             all                                     trust
```

The path is correct, because I can connect through:

```
:~# psql --host=/opt/jasperreports-server-cp-5.1.0/postgresql/ --user=postgres
```

Comment: It works for me: `$conf['servers'][0]['host'] = '/var/run/postgresql'` on debian. Search for error messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    // If extra login security is true, then logins via phpPgAdmin with no
    // password or certain usernames (pgsql, postgres, root, administrator)
    // will be denied. Only set this false once you have read the FAQ and
    // understand how to change PostgreSQL's pg_hba.conf to enable
    // passworded local connections.
    $conf['extra_login_security'] = false;
```

This value was true on default, that's why I could not login.